# error: expression cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++

there is my.hpp :

```
#include <utility>

#ifndef ROBBINS_MONRO
#define ROBBINS_MONRO


template <class Func, class DetermSeq, class RandomV, class RNG>
std::pair<double,double> robbins_monro(const Func & h, double x_init, double alpha, const DetermSeq & epsilon, RandomV & U, RNG & G, long unsigned N){
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        x_init-= epsilon(i+1)(h(x_init) - alpha + U(G));
    }
    return std::make_pair(x_init, h(x_init));
}


#endif
```

And my test1a.cpp :

```
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include "robbinsmonro.hpp"
#include <iostream>



int main() {
    auto h = [](double x) { return 1/(1+exp(-x)); };
    double alpha = 2/3;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> U(-0.1,0.1);
    double x_init=0;
    auto epsilon = [] (long unsigned n) { return 1/(1+n); };
    std::mt19937 G(time(NULL));
    std::pair<double,double> a,b;
    a = robbins_monro(h, x_init, alpha, epsilon,  U, G, 1000000);
    b = robbins_monro(h, x_init, alpha, epsilon,  U, G, 10000000);
    std::cout << "Pour N= 1000000, on obtient x= " << std::get<0>(a) << " (et h(x)= " << std::get<1>(b) << ")" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Pour N= 10000000, on obtient x= " << std::get<0>(b) << " (et h(x)= " << std::get<1>(b) << ")" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have this error :

> error: expression cannot be used as a function

For the line :

x_init-= epsilon(i+1)(h(x_init) - alpha + U(G));

I don't understand because all the terms are double, not "a function"

Comment: Note that `2/3` is zero, not `2.0/3.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to do a multiplication here, for which you need the `*` operator:

```
x_init -= epsilon(i+1) * (h(x_init) - alpha + U(G));
                  //  ^^^
```

The expression you wrote makes sense in usual algebra, but in c++, the second parentheses becomes a function call on the result of `epsilon(i+1)`. Since this returns an `unsigned long long`, it's not a function, and you can't call it.

Also, in this lambda:

```
[] (long unsigned n) { return 1/(1+n); };
```

unless `n` is `0`, this function will always return `0`, because you are doing integer division. Instead, you can do:

```
[] (long unsigned n) { return 1. /(1+n); };
```